How to generate a PDF from a 2MB HTML file using the iText library
I'm using iText to generate PDFs from HTML files. It works efficiently for files under 1MB, but larger files (over 2MB) take up to 2 hours to process. Is there a solution to improve performance?
For HTML files around 6-7 MB, is there an efficient way to generate a PDF using iText?
public static void main() throws IOException {
    File htmlSource = new File("input.html");
    File pdfDest = new File("output.pdf");
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(htmlSource),new FileOutputStream(pdfDest), converterProperties);
}


Well for starters you could start using a BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream to see if that helps.

which versions are you using? can you share the 2Mb HTML file?
